# Hibernate ServiceRegistry class missing?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting started with hibernate and I'm following this tutorial

https://www.javaguides.net/2018/11/hibernate-hello-world-tutorial.html

But when running my jar I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry
```

Which is pretty self-explaining but I can't figure out how to get it

I've tried adding

```
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
```

But with no luck

The minimal structure from the tutorial is:

pom file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

App.java

```
package net.javaguides.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("Ramesh", "Fadatare", "rameshfadatare@javaguides.com");
        Transaction transaction = null;

        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(student);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package net.javaguides.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Manjaro Linux, if it matters

Comment: Could you include a minimal working example in your post? The first link works only for people who disable the AdBlock

Comment: The Tutorial is very old and using Hibernate 3. You should look for a tutorial that uses the most recent Hibernate Version

Comment: The tutorial is for 5.3.7.Final and is honestly the most recent one I could find.
Added some copy paste code

Comment: Bump... that's it

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was that Hibernate itself was missing from my produced jar(and it's target folder)

The solution is to either pack the dependencies in the jar itself or in the target folder(and have a classpath reference them?)

I went with the first but this slows down re-compiles:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.fistmedia.javapp.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```